# Grails project with JQuery without Plugin

Tags: jquery, grails

I am trying to set up a simple Grails 2.1.1 application that will use JQuery

I have one Controller called "TestController" and a rightly located index.gsp.
I add the JQuery libraries  manually, I am not using the Grails Plugin. I put "jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js" and "jquery-1.8.0.min.js" in web-app/js (the location is correct since I can see the code of Jquery when I browse the my own code in the browser and click the reference link)

I want to run the [Autocomplete sample of JQuery](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). The code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js" type="javascript"/>
<script src="../js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="javascript"/>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source:availableTags
        });
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>


<div class="demo">

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

The Autocomplete does not work so far. What am I missing?

Comment: Any errors in javascript console?

Comment: $ is not defined. Same when replacing $ with JQuery

Comment: Try linking the JS files with resources - JQuery probably isnt being loaded. <g:resource dir="js" file="jquery-1.8.0.min.js" />

Comment: Does not change anything:                                    <script src="${resource(dir: 'js', file: 'jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js')}" type="javascript"></script>
    <script src="${resource(dir: 'js', file: 'jquery-1.8.0.min.js')}" type="javascript"></script>

Answer (score 1):

change the reference to jQuery:

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

at least, that fixed your example on my computer... :-)

Comment: Doesn't help. I also make sure that the JQuery Plugin is not installed and main.gsp and the root index.gsp are completely empty. So there is only one GSP with the two references....

Comment: Also now I get the following errors: "$("#tags").autocomplete is not a function" and "jQuery is not defined", the latter links INTO the jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.jsLine: 5

Comment: that's strange. btw: your problem does not depend on grails - it's just an HTML file which grails crates. I took your example and saved it locally, added my jquery files and the changes mentioned above made it work... which browser are you using? I tested with ff and ie.

Comment: btw: selfclosing script-tags cause sometimes problems -> view source in FF showed me this problem.

Comment: and a comparison with other pages showed me the `type="text/javascript"` change - only when I changes this attribute, it worked on my machine

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

- Made sure that no JQuery Plugin is installed
- JQuery references in the correct order

  ```
  <script src="../js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          var availableTags = [
              "ActionScript",
              "AppleScript",
              "Asp",
              "BASIC",
              "C",
              "C++",
              "Clojure",
              "COBOL",
              "ColdFusion",
              "Erlang",
              "Fortran",
              "Groovy",
              "Haskell",
              "Java",
              "JavaScript",
              "Lisp",
              "Perl",
              "PHP",
              "Python",
              "Ruby",
              "Scala",
              "Scheme"
          ];
          $("#tags").autocomplete({
              source:availableTags
          });
      });
  </script>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

why not use references to the resources dir?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir:'js',file:'jquery-1.8.0.min.js')}"</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir:'js',file:'jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js')}"> </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your experiencing a bug with Grails, which took me a while to find out. 
For some reason the first javascript entry is ignored for processing. 
To fix your issue you need to add an extra script tag before your resources. like so.

```
<script type="javascript"/></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js" type="javascript"/>
<script src="../js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="javascript"/>
```

Once this is done retest.. it should be fixed.

Comment: ? can't be a bug in grails since grails just delivers the HTML code to the browser which executes the javascript. Maybe it's a problem with the template delivered with grails, but I never had this problem.

Comment: I know its an issue, but never had time to go into the detail of why it occurred, but it does occur. it took a while and since then all my gsp's has the blank javascript script set.. never had a problem since.

Comment: I certainly don't do this and I don't have any issues - so at least its not a bug in grails 2.0.4 and above

Comment: We are using version 1.3.7-9, so its probably been fixed by now.