# "Autocomplete is not a function" Javascript error

Tags: javascript, grails, autocomplete

In my Grails project (version 2.2.1) I'm using the following Javascript code in two different GSP pages.

```
<g:javascript>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/medicalOfficeManager/Patient/getAllPatients",
        dataType: "json",
        success : function(response) {
            //Create a map.
            var data =
                    $.map(response, function(item){
                        console.log("id: " + item.id);
                        console.log("name: " + item.surname + " "+ item.name);
                        return{
                            id: item.id,
                            value: item.surname + " " + item.name
                        }
                    });


            $("#patient_textField").autocomplete({
                source: data,
                select: function (event, ui){
                    console.log("selected id:" + ui.item.id);
                    console.log("selected name:" + ui.item.value);

                    //when a country is selected(ie: type China and press enter),
                    //change the value of hidden field to the country's id.
                    $('#patient_id').val(ui.item.id);
                    console.log("patient value = "+ $('#patient_id').val());
                }
            });

        }
    });

});
</g:javascript>
```

In one GSP everything works as expected, in another one, looking at Javascript console, I have the following error:

> $(...).autocomplete is not a function

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780399/grails-project-with-jquery-without-plugin) discussion, but it does not work for me.

Any suggestion?

EDIT: I've noticed that the only difference betweeen pages is that, in the not working one, it is loaded the bundle-bundle_core_head.js, but I don't see where it is loaded in gsp page...

EDIT2: there was a component loading in other gsp that includes an earlier version of JQuery and JQuery UI, but I need that component because, if I comment it, another field that allows me to choose date and time does not work. Is it possible to use both?

Comment: If you followed it why it doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `autocomplete` function is likely provided by a jQuery plugin that you are including in one page, but not the other. View the source of each page and compare the `<script>` elements in each.

Comment: I've seen that the only one difference in the two is that it is loaded the following script: .../static/bundle-bundle_core_head.js but I don't know where it is loaded...is there a way to know where this script is loaded?

Comment: That file is probably loaded in the layout, which could be used by one GSP but not the other. If none of this makes much sense, you probably need to learn about the resources plugin (which you appear to be using) and how Sitemesh templates are applied to GSPs